# What is the reason for this seemingly inconsistent inflection around masculine genitive?

Tags: grammar, genitive, inflection

I found the following sentence in a book:

> (...) bemerkte ich (...) eine mir auffällige Übereinstimmung bezüglich des Inhaltes der drei Zeitungsfetzen: sie enthielten nämlich alle drei einen Bericht über **die Ermordung eines reichen französischen Kaufmannes in Blidah**.

I was confused by this; the core seems to be "die Ermordung des Kaufmannes", which is the expected inflection of masculine genitive; but why "reichen französischen" and not "reiches französisches"?

Comment: The correct genitive is "eines reichen französischen Kaufmannes", it just happens to look like an accusative...

Comment: Thanks, I mixed up the cases, this is obviously genitive, edited to reflect. The question still stands about the endings of the two attributes of the Kaufmann. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, as you see on inflection tables the masculine accusative of *reich* is always *reichen*. It doesn't matter if it's weak, strong or mixed inflection.

But as @Anke already said in a comment it's genitive case here. You ask: "Wessen Ermordung? Die eines reichen franz. Kaufmannes".

Again, have a look at the table and you'll notice that the ending must be an *-n*.

> Mixed inflection (with ein, kein, possessive pronouns etc.)
>   Genitive: eines   reichen

You don't need to look up that for every single adjective. Inflection rules in German are quite complicated but consistent. You find a general inflection table on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_adjectives#Weak_and_strong_inflection).

Comment: Thanks. I used to think the words around the inflected form of a noun always take on the ending of the article "des" in this case, and was confused by this. What is the rule anyway? Do all adjectives end in "-n" in masculine genitive, or is widely variable?

Comment: @neuviemeporte See my edit.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the other responses, the *Kaufmann* and his attributes in

> Die Ermordung des reichen französischen Kaufmanns

are genitive in relation to the noun "Ermordung" (whose murder? ***Wessen*** Ermordung? -- genitive). The construction as a whole is not an accusative at all. The following would be an accusative:

> Er hat einen reichen französischen Kaufmann ermordet.

Er hat ***wen oder was*** ermordet? -- accusative. As @Anke said, it just happens that the inflections for genitive and accusative look the same for the two adjectives, but it's not accusative, but genitive.

Answer (score 1):

The core can never be 2 nouns (except enumerations)...

We have 2 things here, Ermordung and Kaufmann and it is not an enumeration.

> Die Zeitung berichtet über die Ermordung, den Kaufmann und Uli Hoeneß.

The Kaufmann is connected to Ermordung using a Genitive. What endings adjectives describing Kaufmann get is completely independent of what the function of Ermordung is.

> Die Ermordung des reichen Kaufmannes war eine Lüge. (nom.)
>
> Die Ermordung des reichen Kaufmannes hat jemand beobachtet (acc)
>
> Von der Ermordung des reichen Kaufmannes redet die ganze Stadt (dat.)
>
> Der Schmied ist der Ermordung des reichen Kaufmannes bezichtigt (gen.)

You have to see at as 2 separate boxes that only form one box on a higher semantical level. The connection could also be made using a preposition. The content wouldn't change.

> ... über die Ermordung von dem reichen Kaufmann....

Not nice but those phrasings are out there.