# “Bei” followed by adjectives

Tags: preposition, declension, adjective-ending

I came across this sentence in a weather report:

> Bei schwachem bis mäßigen Südostwind wird es recht warm …

I am aware that *bei* is followed by the dative case and that adjectives in this situation end in *-en*. As I assumed *schwach* was the adjective being used I was therefore expecting *schwachen* rather than *schwachem*.

Is *schwachem* short for *einem schwachen*? Or is *schwachem* an adjective in its own right? In which case, why isn’t it *schwachemen*?

Comment: Related: http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/4928, http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/6636

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adjectives in German are declined differently depending on the presence of a determiner; so-called “weak inflection” and “strong inflection”. It is therefore:

> bei schwachem Wind *(strong inflection)*
> bei dem schwachen Wind, bei einem schwachen Wind *(weak inflection)*

See [Canoo about inflection types](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Wort/Adjektiv/Deklinationstyp/index.html?lang=en#Anchor-Deklinationstypen-35882) (or any textbook, really) for more information.

---

Em1 noted in chat that *mäßigen* is wrong, it should be *mäßigem* as well (*bei schwachem bis mäßigem Südostwind*). Apparently, this is [a transcript of a TV weather forecast](https://www.thoughtco.com/german-4133073), but the original audio is not available (and it would be difficult to hear the difference anyway); thus, the error might be in the transcript or in the original.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply. Canoo looks like a good source of info, and I shall use it in my studies.